# how to compare parts of datetime to string or int in php

Tags: php, string, datetime, int

I need to compare different parts of dattime in php to see when to present a certain text to the user based on both time, day and season
I found an example that gives me every part of datetime I need
but when I compare it with a string value, I get a blank screen
then I tried to compare it with a number, same result
when I call the method without the comparing it does get executed

how can I compare these values and with what ?
here is the code

```
$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
$stringDate = date($dateFormat);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $stringDate);
$dateValue = strtotime($q);                     
$year = $date->format('Y');
$month = $date->format('m');
$days = $date->format('d');
$hour = $date->format('H');
$minute = $date->format('i');
$second = $date->format('s');
```